# How to check if a column in a query can produce NULL?

Tags: postgresql

I am scheming how to implement a type generator for arbitrary SQL queries.

I found that for any query, the simplest way to get the types of every column is to create a temporary table and then inspect that table. However, this tells nothing about which columns can be NULL.

I am interested to find a solution to identifying which columns can be NULL for any arbitrary query with the goal of generating types for that query.

What’s the way to go about it?

Comment: Is this so you can generate a type for your consuming application, or will this type solely stay within your SQL server for its lifespan?

Comment: I don't think you can determine this just by looking at the column definitions. Even a column defined as NOT NULL can be NULL in a result as the result of an outer join

Comment: [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&rdbms2=postgres_12&fiddle=ef1901387f3cafbe30ad1a939a46a644) shows that the query must have internal knowledge of the server code in order to be able to answer such questions - you're [tilting at windmills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Quixote#Tilting_at_windmills) unfortunately!

Comment: @J.D. for consumption of the application.

Comment: @Gajus As others have mentioned, what you're trying to accomplish is unfortunately not realistically possible. It's also not something usually done in the database. This is more so something you should be doing in application code (similar to how ORMs work). Regardless, abstractly speaking, NULL or NOT NULL is a state of a data value snapshotted in time. The columns of a result set are always potentially nullable based on the nondeterministic possibilities that can influence a query, such as how a_horse_with_no_name points out. So there is no deterministic way to accurately define if...

Comment: ...the columns of a result set are NULL or not, technically they're always nullable. Concrete definitions such as a Table or a Class is what determines the constraint on if a field is NULL or not.

Comment: Hypothetically, if I read program that analyzed the query and that could query the database to check the schema, wouldn't that allow me to determine which columns are nullable? Sure, that would require implementing logic for all types of JOINs, CTEs, etc but it seems doable.

Answer (score 2):

Since SQL (with recursive CTEs) is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), figuring out if a column in the result could be NULL or not is probably as complex as the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and cannot be computed.

So either run the query and examine the result or restrict yourself to very simple queries (but even then the problem will be non-trivial).

My personal recommendation is to give up.